# How to recenter extents of my coordinate system in QGIS?

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

How do I change the extents of a projection of the world so that longitude 90W is centered?

I'm working in WGS84.

Perhaps I need to add some clarification of my objective.
I have a dataset of the world
[image]
Which I would like to reproject to look like this.
[image]

One of the packaged CRSs, EPSG:3832 shows something like what I want to do, but I can't figure out how to change the extents at all.
[image]

Let me know if further clarification will help answer this question.

Comment: I'm new to this forum, any advice on how I can rephrase my question to get an answer?

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom crs? For example, if you base your custom crs on an existing projection like Plate Carree, you would be able to change the lon_0 parameter and put -90 : `+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-90 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`